# Change image width to match_parent or center the image in ImageGetter Android

Tags: android, textview

I am fetching images from html using ImageGetter(Code found on StackOverflow) but Images fetched are too small and left aligned, I want to either center align those images or make their width to match parent. Is there any way to do this?

URLImageParser:

```
public class URLImageParser implements Html.ImageGetter {
Context c;
TextView container;

/***
 * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the   container
 * @param t
 * @param c
*/
public URLImageParser(TextView t, Context c) {
this.c = c;
this.container = t;
}

public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

// get the actual source
ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = 
    new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

asyncTask.execute(source);

// return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
// the src tag
return urlDrawable;
}

public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>     {
URLDrawable urlDrawable;

public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
    this.urlDrawable = d;
}

@Override
protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
    String source = params[0];
    return fetchDrawable(source);
}

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) { 
// set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call 
Log.d("height",""+result.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
Log.d("width",""+result.getIntrinsicWidth()); 
urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0+result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0+result.getIntrinsicHeight());  

// change the reference of the current drawable to the result 
// from the HTTP call 
urlDrawable.drawable = result; 

// redraw the image by invalidating the container 
URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();

// For ICS
    URLImageParser.this.container.setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight() 
+ result.getIntrinsicHeight()));

// Pre ICS
URLImageParser.this.container.setEllipsize(null);
} 

/***
 * Get the Drawable from URL
 * @param urlString
 * @return
 */
public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(urlString);
        final URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
        conn.connect(); 
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()); 
        final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
        drawable.setBounds(0,0,bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
        return drawable;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    } 
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to center an image inside the ImageView you use `android:scaleType="centerInside"`.

If you want to zoom the image inside your ImageView so the smallest side will match the size of the ImageView use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

For more ScaleTpzes have a look at: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Is there a reason for this?